# boost::posix_time::time_duration overflow?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I have the following code to get the UNIX time from a posix_time

```
boost::posix_time::ptime time1(boost::gregorian::date(9999,12,31));
boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));

boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = time1-epoch;
cout<<"A: "<<time1<<endl;
cout<<"B: "<<epoch<<endl;
cout<<"C: "<<diff<<endl;

unix_time = diff.total_seconds()
```

gives me this output

```
9999-Dec-31 00:00:00
1970-Jan-01 00:00:00
-1347834:03:51.933722624
```

Now `diff` should not be a negative number. How can I calculate that right? Is there an overflow?

Comment: `long long`, but `diff` is already negative

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: I don't work with the originally 32 bit for unix time

Comment: Good information, because it certainly looks that way.

Comment: Do you set `-DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` for nanosecond precision? I suspect this is the issue, I think this will reduce the supported date range (somewhere in 2262) - though you'd need to investigate the code in detail to see where it's failing..

Answer (score 0):

(btw - I used coliru for the output below, and my local gcc 5.3.1 with boost 1.60 reproduces)

The problem is that you are wanting this number in seconds, so let's try some basic math (and see if I get it right!) :)

```
A: 9999-Dec-31 00:00:00
B: 1970-Jan-01 00:00:00
C: 70389504:00:00
```

So the difference (expressed in hours) is 70389504 hours. Which in seconds is:

70389504 * 60 * 60 => 253402214400 seconds

Now, in the internals of the library, there is a type def for `sec_type` which defaults to `boost::int32_t`. So unless this is set to `int64_t`, the above value will overflow.

As to how to override this, it's not possible unless you hack the `date_time` library, and change the default in `time_resolution_traits.h` from `boost::int32_t` to `boost::int64_`.. (there could be another way, but I haven't investigated the code in detail enough to tell you what that would be..)

Now for your real problem it seems you have this set `-DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` - I suspect you want nanosecond precision? If so, I think you have to reduce the date range supported.

Comment: thx! yes I have set `DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG`. Is there an opportunitiy to detect an overflow?

Comment: Erm, short of hacking the library to set the size of `sec_type` (really `var_type`) to 64-bit if the flag is set, there is no way round this... You could submit a bug report and see if they will fix it for the next release?

Comment: ... or alternatively use the library above as Howard has highlighted - it seems capable of handling the kind of ranges you are after...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in boost::date_time: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3109

A time_duration can represent larger intervals than number of seconds that the type of boost::time_duration::total_seconds() can represent.

If you need the total number of seconds, better use

```
time_duration td = ...
auto seconds = td.ticks() / time_duration::ticks_per_seconds();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always invert positive/negative by subtracting it from zero.

```
diff = 0 - diff; // if diff was negative it will be positive now.
```

Edit 1: Extra info;

Also you formula time1-epoch will calculate the difference between 2 points in time. You should add diff to the current time which should probably results to your liking. (the negative outcome is a logical difference).

Comment: yes, but I want the unix time, which is (seconds sinces `1970-1-1`). A negative number does not meant to be a wrong result, but in this case `9999-12-31` is way later than `1970-1-1` so if there is no overflow, in my opinion the result should be positive.

Comment: From [WikI Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):  "the maximum representable time is Tuesday 2038-01-19". You have a millenniumbug ;-)

Comment: I don't work with the originally 32 bit for unix time

Comment: If your library supports 64bit (which it seems to do because else it would have trown an `bad_year` exception), then I see no errors in your code: Your subtracting a big number from a small number, the result is a negative number. `10 - 100 = -90`

Comment: In my understanding `9999-12-31` is a bigger number than `1970-1-1`. Then this would be a substraction of bigNumber-smallerNumber which schould be positive?!

Comment: By closer inspection, you doing the opposite. So my comment is useless. Then I don't know what is going on. But your problem is probably specific to the boot library. (Sorry that I could not help you out.!).

Answer (score -1):

If you have C++11, perhaps `<chrono>` plus this [free open source date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) which extends `<chrono>` could help?

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date::literals;
    auto time1 = 9999_y/dec/31;
    auto epoch = 1970_y/jan/1;
    std::chrono::seconds diff = date::sys_days{time1} - date::sys_days{epoch};
    std::cout << "A: " << time1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "B: " << epoch << '\n';
    std::cout << "C: " << diff.count() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
A: 9999-12-31
B: 1970-01-01
C: 253402214400
```

Comment: can this library handle nanoseconds precission?

Comment: @user2071938:  Yes and no.  `<chrono>` has a type called `nanoseconds` which is stored in `int64_t`.  That gives it a range of +/- 292 years, not enough range for this example.  If you have a 128 bit type, you can create your own nanoseconds type:  `using nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration<__int128_t, std::nano>;`.  That will have sufficient range for your example.

Comment: On my system `__int128_t` is difficult to work with.  For example you can't stream it out to `cout`.